# Mozilla Rhino - ScriptableObject with custom object?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I am using Mozilla Rhino (JavaScript engine) for my Java application. I defined a ScriptableObject like this:

```
public class TheObj extends ScriptableObject {
public TheObj(){
    //nothing
}
public TheObj(Scriptable scope, Scriptable prototype) {
    super(scope, prototype);
}

@Override
public String getClassName() {
    return "Foo";
}
@JSStaticFunction
public static Foo foo(Foo foo){
    return foo;
}

}
```

And the Foo class is:

```
public class Foo {
  public void bar(){
    System.out.println("it works");
  }
}
```

But when I try `ScriptableObject.defineClass(scope, TheObj.class);` where `scope` is the Scriptable from `Context.enter().initStandardObjects();` then it throws

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Unsupported parameter type "Foo" in method "bar".
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just used `Context.jsToJava(Object, Class<?>);`

(Actually, the function foo() needed to use the Foo parameter as Java, not just return it)